# Artifacts in Glass

Tags: rendering, glass, artifacts

- Blender Version 2.92.0
- Windows 10
- i7
- Intel UHD Graphics 630
- NVIDIA RTX 2080

I am trying to figure out what is happening with the render.  When I try to render in EEVEE, I get areas that appear to be more reflective while in other areas less.

I modeled a simple cube with rounded sides:

• Bevel Modifier->Vertex->Amount = .75, Segments = 2
• Applied the Bevel
• I then selected all the flat side faces.
• Inserting the faces on the sides simultaneously and used Depth to scale the faces outward.
• Insert Faces again set Thickness quite large to create the inner rings
• Loop Tools Relax the centre ring.
• Middle faces were deleted and then filled using Grid Fill.
• Edges added between the centre and outside edge loop.
• Shade Smooth

I did discover a fix:

I deleted the side faces and then fill them with an N-Gon.

Then for each face I used Inset, Relax, Grid Fill, add edge loops.
The render than works fine.

However, this is a bit much, because, I'm basically remodeling the shape.

I've tried to fix it via a number of methods such as:

• Flatten the sides, using Scale Axis 0,
• Loop Tools Relax on all the interior edge loops
• Make Planar Faces on each side
• Normal -> Average Face
I will admit I am guessing.

I would like to know if someone can explain why this happening and if there is a simple fix?

[image]